# Jupyterlab browser crash using plotly

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I recently start using plotly with Juptyter-lab. One of the issue I am facing is Jupyterlab slows down when creating 2 heatmap plots each sizes around 30Mb. Especially if in jupyterlab I decide to make “Create new output view” I can not do anything once output view create, sometimes browser even crash. I try both with Chrome and Firefox, I have latest Jupyterlab and plotly.

If I display same plot using matplotlib, there is no issue. This is definitely related to ***Plotly*** library, I wonder if there is work around for this.